# TexShop behaves differently from command line pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, texshop

My .tex files compile fine with TexShop, but fail with "pdflatex" issued from the command line. Specifically, the command line version fails to load local images requested by \includegraphics{}, and also pauses for long times as it compiles. TeXShop zooms along, and finds all images. Both are run from the same directory.

TexLive 2021 is installed. The command line is using the correct binary, since "which pdflatex" returns /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex, which is a symlink to /Library/TeX/texbin/pdftex. The TexShop and command line versions are identical (3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22).

The log files do show differences between what TexLive and the command line versions load. For example,the command line version loads /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/**doc**/latex/latex-graphics-companion/inputs/graphics.cfg, whereas the TexLive version loads /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/**tex**/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg. As a result, TexShop loads pdftex.def, and "pdflatex" loads "dvips.def".

So, some of these issues must be related to incorrect path searching.

The TeX-related directories in $PATH are ...:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:... Seems fine.

I recently updated my TexLive distribution, as well as TexShop.

I have no idea what's going on. Suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: your commandline settings are wrong.  either because you have (eg) TEXINPUTS set in the environment, or you have a texmf.cnf somewhere.  Presumably texshop is using the same tex binaries as your commandline and you don't have two tex systems installed? texshop itself is just the editor, if pdflatex is loading dvips.def then it is acting as latex, not pdflatex (ie pdfmode is 0) (that would explain why \includegraphics doesn't work as latex+dvips can not include pdf pr pmg or jpg files, only eps and some legacy bitmap forms.

Comment: Thanks! Unsetting TEXINPUTS seems to have fixed the problem, but I don't understand why. It's been set for years, and I haven't had a problem.It's set to setenv TEXINPUTS ".:$HOMETex:/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist//:", so should be fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: You shouldn’t be setting anything TeX related in the shell if you only have TeX Live installed by MacTeX.

Comment: Yes, removing that search path component helped, but I'm still not sure why including a legitimate path in TEXINPUTS should cause pdflatex to run abnormally. Even if overrides kpathsea, shouldn't it still work the same?